# Conditionally Resolving Module with Webpack

Tags: webpack

Currently working on a ReactJs project which has a dependency on a Bootstrap style UI Framework which is also written by us. The framework was originally developed alongside the main application and was resolved just like any other module..

```
require('./path/to/framework/');
```

In the interest of re-usability in other apps we then made the decision to pull it out of the main app, give it it's own repo and publish it as a public node module so that we could npm install it wherever we wanted and away we go.

A problem has arisen when changes, additions or fixes are required to the framework. It now involves publishing an update to the module, updating to the latest version of the module in whatever app you are developing, checking, and then more than likely going back, fixing and repeating the process again! Not ideal!

The proposed fix was during development to simply replace the require with something like...

```
require('absolute-path-to-framework');
```

pointing it at the local version of the module thus preventing the fix-publish-check-fix loop.

The issue with this is that there are a lot of references to the framework scattered across the app and so understandably Webpack is resolving and bundling both the framework in node_modules AND the 'local' framework wherever the absolute path is pointing to, obviously causing issues with duplicate definitions etc.

I've had a look at the Webpack documentation and it seems like resolve.alias is kind of what I'm looking for but can't quite put the pieces together. Also a few answers on here suggest defining a custom plugin and defining environment variables that you can then use in code...

```
if(ENV.Dev){ 
   require('absolute-path-to-framework');
} else {
   require('framework');
}
```

I'm not really keen on littering the app with if statements like this so hoping there is an alternative??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are very close, and you can combine a couple of the ideas you mentioned to come up with an efficient solution.

If you make use of resolve aliasing in your webpack config, you could do a one-off check for a particular node environment variable (such as NODE_ENV=development) when setting the value of the alias.

E.g.

**webpack.config.js**

```
{
  ...lots of other webpack config here...
  ...
  resolve: {
    ...
    alias: {
      framework123: ( process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ) ? 'absolute-path-to-framework' : 'framework-module-name'
    }
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

And then just use the alias key/name with `require()` in your source files which get compiled by webpack.

**entry.js**

```
var framework = require('framework123');
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: awesome, works a treat. thanks.. the only issue i can see now is that the absolute path will be different for all developers so it's going to need changing each time someone comes to work on the project. unless we use another environment variable that they can set to avoid changing the gulpfile each time.